# Ruby on Rails - Change column value in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

I have a rake task that sends an email if `MailCourseWarn.where(needs_warned: true)`. I want that after email is delivered, the `needs_warned` be `false` and not `true`.

Rake task:

```
namespace :course_available do
  desc 'Disparando e-mail de curso disponível'

  task :warn_user => :environment do |t, args|
    MailCourseWarn.where(needs_warned: true).each do |user|
      if user.course.start_at < Date.today
        MailCourseWarnMailer.delay_for(1.seconds, retry: true).course_available(user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I do this? I tried to put on end of taks `user.needs_warned = false`, but doesn't worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Does `user.update! needs_warned: false` work? Your version is changing the record, then throwing it away and not saving it...

Comment: @Phlip I think you should add this as an answer, this is likely the correct response. The poster should have called a `user.save` or used the syntax you noted to save the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update that column in `if` condition. `user.update_attribute(:needs_warned, false)`

For example:

```
namespace :course_available do
  desc 'Disparando e-mail de curso disponível'

  task :warn_user => :environment do |t, args|
    MailCourseWarn.where(needs_warned: true).each do |user|
     if user.course.start_at < Date.today
       MailCourseWarnMailer.delay_for(1.seconds, retry: true).course_available(user)
       user.update_attribute(:needs_warned, false)
     end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked very well. What the difference if I used `user.update! needs_warned: false`? That works to. Thanks.

Comment: @FelipeMarcon Check this out [Different Ways to Set Attributes in ActiveRecord (Rails 4)](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/)

Answer (score 1):

Does `user.update! needs_warned: false` work? Your version is changing the record, then throwing it away and not saving it...

Answer (score 0):

@Philip is right. Your code can even be improved through by inlining the if-condition into the SQL query and performing a mass update. That way you only end up with exactly two SQL queries: (1) for the retrieval of records matching your condition and (2) for a mass update. Otherwise your code might end up performing a lot of queries.

```
namespace :course_available do
  desc 'Disparando e-mail de curso disponível'

  task :warn_user => :environment do
    results = MailCourseWarn
      .joins(:courses)
      .where('needs_warned = ? AND courses.start_date < ?', true, Date.today)

    results.each do |user|
      MailCourseWarnMailer.delay_for(1.seconds, retry: true).course_available(user)
    end

    results.update_all(needs_warned: false)
  end
end
```

Note that I also simplified the code a bit (removed the unnecessary `|t, args|`)